# .Net Core Radio button Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Have a page setup similar to below, HasAnimal is always binding as false - despite yes being selected - any ideas?

cs

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public bool HasAnimal { get; set; }
     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {}
}
```

cshtml

```
<label>Yes</label>
<input asp-for="HasAnimal" type="radio" value="true" checked />
<label>No</label>
<input asp-for="HasAnimal" type="radio" value="false" />
```

Comment: In your case, I advise using checkbox.

Comment: There's only one possible answer, so checkbox wouldn't be the best solution

Comment: No, there are 2 possible variants: ticked or unticked, yes or no, true or false, etc.
bool type can have true or false, no more.